# sendmail: what causes "Deferred Invalid argument" and how do I fix it?

Tags: sendmail

I was testing a script I had written in PHP when I realised that the emails it was meant to send out only went to local addresses. When I logged into WebMin I saw that the sendmail queue had a lot of emails (mine and a bunch of bounces) that had the status "Deferred Invalid argument".

Regardless of which domain the email was going to when I tried to flush it I would see connecting to x.y.z and then "Deferred Invalid argument". This was the same for bounces as well as for the messages that I put in the queue from my script.

I have to assume that since the server was set up no outgoing email has ever been sent which explains a few things.

How do solve this invalid argument issue and get sendmail doing what it's name implies?

**Update:**

After googling this problem I am more confused than ever. [This](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.mail.sendmail/2006-08/msg00366.html) one seems to advocate the use of modifier flags while [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/sendmail-makeconnection-failed-invalid-argument-895782/) says to remove them. I can confirm that this makes no difference at all.

A verbose flush looks like this:

```
Running /var/spool/mqueue/t5PGrXAh030113 (sequence 1 of 4)
<...SNIP...@yahoo.com>... Connecting to mta7.am0.yahoodns.net. via esmtp...
<...SNIP...@yahoo.com>... Connecting to mta5.am0.yahoodns.net. via esmtp...
<...SNIP...@yahoo.com>... Connecting to mta6.am0.yahoodns.net. via esmtp...
<...SNIP...@yahoo.com>... Deferred: Invalid argument

Running /var/spool/mqueue/t5PGrXDm030105 (sequence 2 of 4)
<...SNIP...@hotmail.com>... Connecting to mx3.hotmail.com. via esmtp...
<...SNIP...@hotmail.com>... Connecting to mx4.hotmail.com. via esmtp...
<...SNIP...@hotmail.com>... Connecting to mx2.hotmail.com. via esmtp...
<...SNIP...@hotmail.com>... Connecting to mx1.hotmail.com. via esmtp...
<...SNIP...@hotmail.com>... Deferred: Invalid argument

Running /var/spool/mqueue/t5PGrX8t030093 (sequence 3 of 4)
<...SNIP...@painty.co.uk>... Connecting to painty.co.uk. via esmtp...
<...SNIP...@painty.co.uk>... Deferred: Invalid argument

Running /var/spool/mqueue/t5PGrW31030083 (sequence 4 of 4)
<...SNIP...@gmail.com>... Connecting to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. via esmtp...
<...SNIP...@gmail.com>... Connecting to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. via esmtp...
<...SNIP...@gmail.com>... Connecting to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. via esmtp...
<...SNIP...@gmail.com>... Connecting to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. via esmtp...
<...SNIP...@gmail.com>... Connecting to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. via esmtp...
<...SNIP...@gmail.com>... Deferred: Invalid argument
```

And the raw sendmail configuration file like this:

```
divert(-1)dnl
dnl #
dnl # This is the sendmail macro config file for m4. If you make changes to
dnl # /etc/mail/sendmail.mc, you will need to regenerate the
dnl # /etc/mail/sendmail.cf file by confirming that the sendmail-cf package is
dnl # installed and then performing a
dnl #
dnl #     make -C /etc/mail
dnl #
include(`/usr/share/sendmail-cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl
VERSIONID(`setup for linux')dnl
OSTYPE(`linux')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Do not advertize sendmail version.
dnl #
dnl define(`confSMTP_LOGIN_MSG', `$j Sendmail; $b')dnl
dnl #
dnl # default logging level is 9, you might want to set it higher to
dnl # debug the configuration
dnl #
dnl define(`confLOG_LEVEL', `9')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Uncomment and edit the following line if your outgoing mail needs to
dnl # be sent out through an external mail server:
dnl #
dnl define(`SMART_HOST', `smtp.your.provider')dnl
dnl #
define(`confDEF_USER_ID', ``8:12'')dnl
dnl define(`confAUTO_REBUILD')dnl
define(`confTO_CONNECT', `1m')dnl
define(`confTRY_NULL_MX_LIST', `True')dnl
define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES', `True')dnl
define(`PROCMAIL_MAILER_PATH', `/usr/bin/procmail')dnl
define(`ALIAS_FILE', `/etc/aliases')dnl
define(`STATUS_FILE', `/var/log/mail/statistics')dnl
define(`UUCP_MAILER_MAX', `2000000')dnl
define(`confUSERDB_SPEC', `/etc/mail/userdb.db')dnl
define(`confPRIVACY_FLAGS', `authwarnings,novrfy,noexpn,restrictqrun')dnl
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The following allows relaying if the user authenticates, and disallows
dnl # plaintext authentication (PLAIN/LOGIN) on non-TLS links
dnl #
dnl define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A p')dnl
dnl # 
dnl # PLAIN is the preferred plaintext authentication method and used by
dnl # Mozilla Mail and Evolution, though Outlook Express and other MUAs do
dnl # use LOGIN. Other mechanisms should be used if the connection is not
dnl # guaranteed secure.
dnl # Please remember that saslauthd needs to be running for AUTH. 
dnl #
dnl TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
dnl define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Rudimentary information on creating certificates for sendmail TLS:
dnl #     cd /usr/share/ssl/certs; make sendmail.pem
dnl # Complete usage:
dnl #     make -C /usr/share/ssl/certs usage
dnl #
dnl define(`confCACERT_PATH', `/etc/pki/tls/certs')dnl
dnl define(`confCACERT', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt')dnl
dnl define(`confSERVER_CERT', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/sendmail.pem')dnl
dnl define(`confSERVER_KEY', `/etc/pki/tls/certs/sendmail.pem')dnl
dnl #
dnl # This allows sendmail to use a keyfile that is shared with OpenLDAP's
dnl # slapd, which requires the file to be readble by group ldap
dnl #
dnl define(`confDONT_BLAME_SENDMAIL', `groupreadablekeyfile')dnl
dnl #
dnl define(`confTO_QUEUEWARN', `4h')dnl
dnl define(`confTO_QUEUERETURN', `5d')dnl
dnl define(`confQUEUE_LA', `12')dnl
dnl define(`confREFUSE_LA', `18')dnl
define(`confTO_IDENT', `0')dnl
dnl FEATURE(delay_checks)dnl
FEATURE(`no_default_msa', `dnl')dnl
FEATURE(`smrsh', `/usr/sbin/smrsh')dnl
FEATURE(`mailertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/mailertable.db')dnl
FEATURE(`virtusertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable.db')dnl
FEATURE(redirect)dnl
FEATURE(always_add_domain)dnl
FEATURE(use_cw_file)dnl
FEATURE(use_ct_file)dnl
dnl #
dnl # The following limits the number of processes sendmail can fork to accept 
dnl # incoming messages or process its message queues to 20.) sendmail refuses 
dnl # to accept connections once it has reached its quota of child processes.
dnl #
dnl define(`confMAX_DAEMON_CHILDREN', `20')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Limits the number of new connections per second. This caps the overhead 
dnl # incurred due to forking new sendmail processes. May be useful against 
dnl # DoS attacks or barrages of spam. (As mentioned below, a per-IP address 
dnl # limit would be useful but is not available as an option at this writing.)
dnl #
dnl define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_THROTTLE', `3')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The -t option will retry delivery if e.g. the user runs over his quota.
dnl #
FEATURE(local_procmail, `', `procmail -t -Y -a $h -d $u')dnl
FEATURE(`access_db', `hash -T<TMPF> -o /etc/mail/access.db')dnl
FEATURE(`blacklist_recipients')dnl
EXPOSED_USER(`root')dnl
dnl #
dnl # For using Cyrus-IMAPd as POP3/IMAP server through LMTP delivery uncomment
dnl # the following 2 definitions and activate below in the MAILER section the
dnl # cyrusv2 mailer.
dnl #
dnl define(`confLOCAL_MAILER', `cyrusv2')dnl
dnl define(`CYRUSV2_MAILER_ARGS', `FILE /var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The following causes sendmail to only listen on the IPv4 loopback address
dnl # 127.0.0.1 and not on any other network devices. Remove the loopback
dnl # address restriction to accept email from the internet or intranet.
dnl #
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Name=MTA,Port=smtp,Modifiers=bh')
dnl #
dnl # The following causes sendmail to additionally listen to port 587 for
dnl # mail from MUAs that authenticate. Roaming users who can't reach their
dnl # preferred sendmail daemon due to port 25 being blocked or redirected find
dnl # this useful.
dnl #
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=submission, Name=MSA, M=Ea')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The following causes sendmail to additionally listen to port 465, but
dnl # starting immediately in TLS mode upon connecting. Port 25 or 587 followed
dnl # by STARTTLS is preferred, but roaming clients using Outlook Express can't
dnl # do STARTTLS on ports other than 25. Mozilla Mail can ONLY use STARTTLS
dnl # and doesn't support the deprecated smtps; Evolution <1.1.1 uses smtps
dnl # when SSL is enabled-- STARTTLS support is available in version 1.1.1.
dnl #
dnl # For this to work your OpenSSL certificates must be configured.
dnl #
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtps, Name=TLSMTA, M=s')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The following causes sendmail to additionally listen on the IPv6 loopback
dnl # device. Remove the loopback address restriction listen to the network.
dnl #
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`port=smtp,Addr=::1, Name=MTA-v6, Family=inet6')dnl
dnl #
dnl # enable both ipv6 and ipv4 in sendmail:
dnl #
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Name=MTA-v4, Family=inet, Name=MTA-v6, Family=inet6, M=h')
dnl #
dnl # We strongly recommend not accepting unresolvable domains if you want to
dnl # protect yourself from spam. However, the laptop and users on computers
dnl # that do not have 24x7 DNS do need this.
dnl #
FEATURE(`accept_unresolvable_domains')dnl
dnl #
dnl FEATURE(`relay_based_on_MX')dnl
dnl # 
dnl # Also accept email sent to "localhost.localdomain" as local email.
dnl # 
LOCAL_DOMAIN(`localhost.localdomain')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The following example makes mail from this host and any additional
dnl # specified domains appear to be sent from mydomain.com
dnl #
dnl MASQUERADE_AS(`mydomain.com')dnl
dnl #
dnl # masquerade not just the headers, but the envelope as well
dnl #
dnl FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
dnl #
dnl # masquerade not just @mydomainalias.com, but @*.mydomainalias.com as well
dnl #
dnl FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
dnl #
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost.localdomain)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(mydomainalias.com)dnl
dnl MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(mydomain.lan)dnl
MAILER(smtp)dnl
MAILER(procmail)dnl
dnl MAILER(cyrusv2)dnl
FEATURE(`genericstable', `hash -o /etc/mail/genericstable.db')dnl
FEATURE(`relay_based_on_MX')
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant log entries in sendmail log file?

Comment: I can just after I google where to find them.

Comment: Google is my friend: http://serverfault.com/questions/59602/where-to-check-log-of-sendmail (as is SE). Wow, that log file is verbose in the extreme: spamd entries and a fair few bounces being stuck but not telling *me* anything what am I looking for here?

Answer (score 0):

### Sendmail: Forcing delivery of queuened messages in verbose mode

As root push delivery of the queened messages in verbose mode with full SMTP transcript.

1. use mailq to get queueid-s (queueue identifiers of the messages)
2. use `sendmail -v -qI...` to push the choosen message in verbose mode
   e.g. `sendmail -v -qIt5PGrXAh030113`

Comment: sendmail -v -qI justs gives the same as the flush log I posted under update. It hangs for a good long while before it does that but otherwise... Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Can you telnet smtp port on the host sendmail tries to contact?  Do you get SMTP greeting message? `telnet mta7.am0.yahoodns.net 25`

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove `b` flag from Modifiers in DAEMON_OPTONS in sendmail.mc
`b bind to interface through which mail has been received for outgoing message`

Old:

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Name=MTA,Port=smtp,Modifiers=bh')
```

New:

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Name=MTA,Port=smtp,Modifiers=h')
```

2) generate new sendmail.cf file from modified sendmail.mc

3) restart/reload sendmail daemon